# Connecting to DB2 database

Tags: db2, toad

I get the following error when I try to connect Toad for DB2:

> ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been
>   detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication
>   API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected:
>   "10.99.13.5".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv". 
>   Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001

[image]

Attached is my connection properties. Any help connecting would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tipical problem when the client cannot reach the database. There could be different reasons:

- Closed port in the local (client) machine. (firewall outbound)
- If using local catalog, check if everything is correct (db2 catalog database, db2 catalog tcpip node). If using direct connection skip this step.
- Routing problem (iptables ou network firewall)
- Database server with closed port (inbonud) - netstat -nato check port.
- Instance down (ps -ef or task center in windows)
- DB2COMM registry variable is not set to tcpip
- Port number is not correctly mapped to service name (instance configuration, use number instead)
- Database name is not correct (connect locally in the database server)

You can do a telnet from the Windows (client) machine to the server via telnet

```
telnet databaseServerIP portNumber
```

Even, if the db2 server is in the same machine, you can do a localhost telnet in order to see that the instance can receive TCP connections

```
telnet localhost 50000
```

Once you can do that successfully, you can connect to the database.

Comment: There are many reasons for this problem, check in Internet for more clues. This is most of the time a configuration problem, but outside DB2.