# Connect to db2 by toad

Tags: linux, db2, toad, db2-luw

I try to connect to DB2 by toad in window 7.

But return error:

```
ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected.

Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used:
"SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "192.168.1.22". 
Communication function detecting the error: "selectForConnectTimeout". 
Protocol specific error code(s): "0", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
```

servicer system: CentOS 7

DB2 database: V9.7

I already execute `systemctl sto firewalld.service`.(stop firewall), And execute `db2 "connect to testbase user admin using password"` succeed in CentOS.

I try `telnet 192.168.1.22 50000` in window 7 fail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to DB2 database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987937/connecting-to-db2-database)

Answer (score 0):

DB2 server on Cent OS 7:
if 'db2 connect to ~ user ~ using' works, that means TCP/IP connection on the server works.

Assuming 192.168.1.22/50000 is DB2 server IP/port, if 'telnet 192.168.1.22 50000'
fails, that's something with firewall between DB2 client and server.
Something prevents port 50000 in the middle if just 'ping 192.168.1.2' works and port 50000 can't be connected.