# While I'm working one of the "data bases and sql dor Data science" , i found this message

Tags: db2

> "Unable to connect:  [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "169.44.98.103".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "110", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001 SQLCODE=-30081"

Who can help me please?

Comment: Duplicate of [Connecting to DB2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987937/connecting-to-db2-database)

Answer (score 0):

SQL30081N with reason code 110 is (assuming you are on Linux) is a `ETIMEDOUT`, which is a connection timeout.

> Connection has reached the network timeout limit and is terminated by network
>   Timeout by tcpip layer

Usually this is network issue

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/577801